# Webcam stream doesn't work on Logitech E2500

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, webcam, video-streaming, raspberry-pi

I'm currently trying to get webcam streaming to work on a Logitech E2500 with ffmpeg.

Running the command gives me some kind of buffer length error.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/ffmpeg-dmo-1.0 $ sudo /usr/sbin/webcam.sh
```

This script contains the following:

```
ffserver -f /etc/ffserver.conf & ffmpeg -v verbose -r 5 -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost/webcam.ffm
```

It gives the following output:

```
ffserver version 1.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developersffmpeg version 1.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
built on Dec  2 2012 17:56:37 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-12+rpi1)
configuration: 
libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101

built on Dec  2 2012 17:56:37 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-12+rpi1)
configuration: 
libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x250a620] [3]Capabilities: 5000001
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x250a620] The V4L2 driver changed the video from 320x240 to 320x232
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x250a620] Buffer len [0] = 40960 != 74240
/dev/video0: Operation not permitted
```

*Contents of /etc/ffserver.conf:*

```
Port 1025
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxClients 10
MaxBandwidth 50000
NoDaemon

<Feed webcam.ffm>
file /tmp/webcam.ffm
FileMaxSize 10M
</Feed>

<Stream webcam.mjpeg>
Feed webcam.ffm
Format mjpeg
VideoSize 320x240
VideoFrameRate 10
VideoBitRate 2000
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 10
</Stream>
```

What is going on here and how do I fix this? Answers are much appreciated.

Comment: It contains the following command: `ffserver -f /etc/ffserver.conf & ffmpeg -v verbose -r 5 -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://localhost/webcam.ffm`

Comment: Per [this comment](http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/04/how-to-stream-a-webcam-from-the-raspberry-pi/#comment-959) it seems your camera produces MJPEG and video4linux2 can't handle this properly. Maybe try adding a `-c:v mjpeg` before the `-f video4linux2` option.

Comment: Thanks, tried it and it spat out the exact same error. However, the post you linked is interesting. Maybe `v4l2-ctl` might contain a solution. Installing v4l-utils now.

Comment: You can cut out all of the ffserver stuff to clarify the issue as in output to a file instead. See the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` to show camera capabilities. Also see the ffmpeg V4L2 input device option `-list_formats all`. Then choose the desired format with `-input_format` (such as `mjpeg` or `yuyv422`). Choose size with `-video_size` (such as 640x480).

Comment: Tried _everything_ I could think of. The camera simply doesn't work. Moved the camera to my Linux Mint laptop and it refuses to work there either.

Comment: Bought a different camera; a Trust Nium HD. There's nothing HD about it but video quality is pretty decent even under low lighting conditions. Streaming works out of the box on this model. Streaming over network currently works at 1 fps, currently configuring that right now. Thank you very much for all your answers, it didn't help with the first camera but it certainly has given me pointers to a much better understanding of ffmpeg and encoding video in general.